# get All Contacts from Mobile android

Tags: android, contacts

I want to get all contact number from mobile 
I am using the following code but it is giving only contact numbers which are in mobile not of sim

```
private void getContactList() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

    if ((cur != null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {
        while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    ContactsPlacer obj = new ContactsPlacer();
                    obj.setContactname(name);
                    obj.setContactnumber(phoneNo);
                    names.add(obj);

                }
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
    if(cur!=null){
        cur.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is code for getting all contact from device

```
 private void getAllContacts() {
    try {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Read Contact permission not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            contactVOList = new ArrayList();
            ContactVO contactVO;

            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                    if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                        contactVO = new ContactVO(pref.getUser_ID(),phoneNumberArrayList);
                        contactVO.setContactName(name);

                        Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                new String[]{id},
                                null);
                        if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                            String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(" ", "");
                            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.trim();
                            String number = "+91#1234*121#";
                            number=phoneNumber.replaceAll("[\\D]", "");
                            contactVO.setContactNumber(number);
                            phoneNumberArrayList.add(number);
                        }

                        phoneCursor.close();

                        Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                new String[]{id}, null);
                        while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                            String emailId = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                        }
                        emailCursor.close();
                        contactVOList.add(contactVO);
                    }
                }
                cursor.close();
                if (contactVOList.size() > 0) {
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            CallAPI();
                        }
                    }, 1000);


                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and Added below code for get SIM contact

```
Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");Cursor cursorSim = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri, null, null,null, null);

     while (cursorSim.moveToNext()) {           
         listName.add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("name")));
         listContactId.add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("_id")));      
         listMobileNo.add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("number")));
        }
```

Comment: it will give all contacts from mobile and sim in sorted manner